# TypeError: password_change() got an unexpected keyword argument 'form'

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am trying to add custom class to django password change form by extending to my custom form. But keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: password_change() got an unexpected keyword argument 'form'
```

Custom form that i use for the change password:
Note: I tried extending to SetPasswordForm as well since PasswordChangeForm is a subclass of it but no dice.
userapp.forms:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import SetPasswordForm, PasswordChangeForm

attrs_dict = {'class':'required form-control'}

    class CustomChangePasswordForm(PasswordChangeForm):
        old_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict))
        new_password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict))
        new_password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict))
```

added this line in urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/password/change/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', {'form': CustomChangePasswordForm}),
url(r'^accounts/register/$', register, { 'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend','form_class':UserRegistrationFormz}, name='registration_register'),
url(r'^accounts/vendor-register/$', register, { 'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend','form_class':VendorRegistrationForm}, name='vendor_register'),
url(r'^accounts/', include(regUrls)),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
{'form': CustomChangePasswordForm}
```

to

```
{'password_change_form': AdminPasswordChangeForm}
```

Reference: [Source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L254)